# What is the source of Dr. Dolittle's ability to talk to animals?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, dr-dolittle

In the [*Dr. Dolittle* film series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dr._Dolittle_%28film%29), how does Dolittle talk to animals? Is it just a genetic trait? A gift from God? Alien experimentation? Did one of his ancestors sell his soul to the devil,  or get cursed by a witch?

Comment: What film adaptation of Dr. Dolittle are you actually asking about here? If you're asking about the general character or the original children's book, I'm afraid your question is off-topic. And if you're asking about all possible film adaptations it is too broad.

Comment: I'm afraid you *have* to choose.

Comment: Technically, "Dr. Dolittle" refers to the Eddie Murphy films. "Doctor Dolittle" is the Rex Harrison version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you probably know, *Doctor Dolittle* was originally a series of books; in the first such story, from 1920, the Dr. learns to talk to animals from his pet parrot. Some of the film adaptations, if they follow the books closely enough, include this plot element in them.

Unfortunately, the most recent film adaptation, the Eddie Murphy series of films, does not follow the source material at all. Early in the first movie we see a very young Dolittle talking to his dog, which prompts his parents to freak out a bit and get rid of the dog. As far as I know, there is never any explanation why he's able to do this, only that he's had the ability since he was a child.

Comment: And his daughter is later revealed to also have the ability, so the movies imply that it's "genetic".

Comment: @Catija apparently, daughterS. Apparently there are 3 other movies in the series. Unless direct to dvd don't count (they really don't :P)