# In the 1967 film version of Doctor Dolittle, what is the source of his ability to speak to animals?

Tags: plot-explanation, doctor-dolittle

In the [1967 musical version](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0061584/) of the 'Dr Dolittle' story, Doctor John Dolittle is able to converse freely with a wide range of creatures.

So what is the source of Dr Dolittle's ability to grunt and squeak and squawk with the animals? Is it genetic, magical, learned or something else?

Comment: For those tempted to close as a dupe, please note that a *similar* question (http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/50461/what-is-the-source-of-dr-dolittles-ability-to-talk-to-animals) is specifically about the 1998 [Eddie Murphy film series](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118998/), not the splendid 1967 Rex Harrison musical film.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson  - You'll note my restraint in not referring to it as the *execrable* 1998 Eddie Murphy film series

Comment: I don't think the date for the tag is necessary. The films have different titles. A tag wiki should be sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

In the very first Doctor Dolittle book, '[The Story of Doctor Dolittle](http://etc.usf.edu/lit2go/221/the-story-of-doctor-dolittle/5616/chapter-2-animal-language/)', the titular doctor is taught to speak the "*language of the animals*" by his pet parrot, Polynesia

> "What would have been the good?" said Polynesia, dusting some
>   cracker–crumbs off her left wing. "You wouldn't have understood me if
>   I had."
>
> "Tell me some more," said the Doctor, all excited; and he rushed over
>   to the dresser–drawer and came back with the butcher's book and a
>   pencil. "Now don't go too fast—and I'll write it down. This is
>   interesting—very interesting—something quite new. Give me the Birds'
>   A.B.C. first—slowly now."
>
> **So that was the way the Doctor came to know that animals had a
>   language of their own and could talk to one another. And all that
>   afternoon, while it was raining, Polynesia sat on the kitchen table
>   giving him bird words to put down in the book.**

In the [1967 film version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Dolittle_(film)) the genesis is extremely quite similar. The good Doctor is well aware that animals have language and is studying a wide range of animal languages (notably halibut and goldfish) but is quite surprised to find that animals have also been studying human languages and that parrots are quite capable of speaking human. His parrot then takes it upon itself to teach him to speak properly.

> **Dolittle:** *Animals actually talk to one another?!*
>
> **Parrot:** *But of course we can*
>
> **Dolittle:** *I knew parrots could talk*
>
> **Parrot:** *Parrots are the finest linguists in the animal kingdom*